# i cant create a Scheduler instance in spring mvc using quartz

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, quartz-scheduler

hi i'm working in a spring mvc project using quartz and i want to create a Scheduler instance but i have the following error when i try to do this:

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
```

error: `Default constructor cannot handle exception type SchedulerException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor`

this is my maven depencies

```
<!-- QuartzJobBean in spring-context-support.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring + Quartz need transaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this is the class where i try to create a Scheduler object

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.quartz.Job;

import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;

import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;




public class PrintSomething implements Job{



    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();


    public void execute(JobExecutionContext ctx) 

    {
        System.out.printf(new Locale("es", "MX"), "%tc a task is printed...%n", new java.util.Date());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getScheduler`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html#getScheduler()) throws a checked exception which needs to be handled in a code block rather than the class block.

Typically you would not include the `Scheduler` code within the `Job` itself. Create a separate Scheduler management class where the a separate method can be used to handle the scheduling functionality.

```
public class JobScheduler {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         // specify the job' s details..
         JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(PrintSomething.class)
                                   .withIdentity("MyId")
                                   .build();
         ... // create trigger

         //schedule the job
         SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
         Scheduler scheduler = schFactory.getScheduler();
         scheduler.start();
         scheduler.scheduleJob(job, someTrigger);
      } catch (SchedulerException e) { // handle exception here
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```